# w_scan cross compile issue

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I download the `w_scan` project(a small command line utility used to perform frequency scans for DVB and ATSC transmissions.) from http://wirbel.htpc-forum.de/w_scan/index_en.html. I also install `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` on my Ubuntu x86_64. 
I use the `./configure --host=arm-linux CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` command to cross-compile, and it generates a binary file. However, I copy that file to my target board and execute that file, it shows `sh: ./w_scan: No such file or directory`.

 I use the `file` command to see information of that binary file, it shows `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, BuildID[sha1]=0x9a584b4720fadf5eb5b77034ac85092daeb728c9, not stripped`.

I found that error message stands the configuration of cross-compile doesn't correct.(reference http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1141792). How can I fix my configuration and correct cross-compile that project, THANKS!

Comment: `file w_scan` what it shows

Comment: Ok then i think its issue with dynamic libraries. 1 simple solution to verify it compile your binary statically. then try it on target

Comment: @vinayhunachyal Thank you very much, I use the `make CFLAGS=-static` to fix the problem. You made my day!!!

Comment: if want your executable dynamic then u need put libraries in target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ./configure --host=arm-linux CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
2. make CFLAGS=-static
3. copy that binary file to my target board, it can execute normally and successfully.

And the file w_scan will shows
`ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, BuildID[sha1]=0x67b7e9f93015607f891c0b77493d9e47059ef6a1, not stripped`.

Comment: This solved the issue by working around the problem.  Most likely your `libc` in the host cross-compiler and deployed on the device are different.

Comment: What's differen between "--host=arm-linux" and "--host=arm-eabi" ?!