# cross-compile from desktop ubuntu to Pandaboard ubuntu c++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cross-compiling, pandaboard

I am trying to cross-compile a simple c++ program from my **ubuntu 11.10 64bit desktop** machine to run on my **panda board** running **Ubuntu12.04** but cannot get the program to run.

I can successfully build and run the program on the panda board by executing

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.6  mytest.cpp -o mytest
```

However, when running the same command on my desktop ubuntu, the executable builds okay but fails to run on the Panda, producing the message

```
-bash: ./mytest: No such file or directory
```

A comparison of toolchain versions, using the --version switch is as follows :
Desktop

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-7ubuntu2) 4.6.1
```

Panda

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

Additionally, when I run ldd on both executables I get

Desktop

```
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6ec4000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6eb2000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6dd0000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb6d66000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f7d000)
```

Panda

```
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6e43000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6e31000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6d4f000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0xb6ce5000)
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6efc000)
```

Does anyone have an idea as to what I could be doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Answered in 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935168/cross-compile-helloworld-for-arm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143086/w-scan-cross-compile-issue?noredirect=1#comment33599828_22143086  compile it static